# Java KeyListener listen to arrow keys without "Windows key"

Tags: java, keylistener

I've made a game that is controlled by the arrow keys. Therefore I have a `KeyListener` listening for the arrow keys:

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getExtendedKeyCode())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            gameManager.up();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            gameManager.down();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            gameManager.right();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            gameManager.left();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now here is my problem:
When I maximize the window using the keyboard by pressing `Windows key` + `Up arrow`, these events still get fired. How can I detect that the `Windows key` has been pressed, while one of the arrow keys got pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Poll for pressed buttons in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624943/poll-for-pressed-buttons-in-java)

Comment: What is described in that post would work for keys like `CTRL` or `SHIFT`, but I didn't find a `WINDOWS_MASK` or something similar.

Comment: Yes I realized it was not a duplicate and retracted my close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an flag in your `KeyListener`, e.g.

```
boolean windowsPressed;

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(event.getExtendedKeyCode() == VK.WINDOWS) windowsPressed = true;
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
{
    switch(event.getExtendedKeyCode())
    {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            if(!windowsPressed) gameManager.up();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            gameManager.down();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            gameManager.right();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            gameManager.left();
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS:
            windowsPressed = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, you'll need a corresponding keyRelease handlers to clear the flag too.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the window key in your keyreleased

```
case: KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS:
//do nothing
```

so it wont register the up button when you pressed the window + up

Comment: I've tried that, but it din't work since I'm pressing a key combination instead of just a single key.